# How to get calligraphy line brush effect in swift using GraphicContext

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, swifty-draw

I want to add calligraphy brush effect just like shown in below Image.for drawing I am using [SwiftyDrawView](https://github.com/Awalz/SwiftyDraw).

[image]

---

Following is code snippets from SwiftyDraw

```
/// Overriding draw(rect:) to stroke paths

  override open func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        guard let context: CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }

        for line in lines {
            context.setLineCap(.round)
            context.setLineJoin(.round)
            context.setLineWidth(line.brush.width)
            // set blend mode so an eraser actually erases stuff
            context.setBlendMode(line.brush.blendMode)
            context.setAlpha(line.brush.opacity)
            context.setStrokeColor(line.brush.color.cgColor)
            context.addPath(line.path)
            context.strokePath()
        }
    }
```

// TouchBegan

```
  override open func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard isEnabled, let touch = touches.first else { return }
        if #available(iOS 9.1, *) {
            guard allowedTouchTypes.flatMap({ $0.uiTouchTypes }).contains(touch.type) else { return }
        }
        guard delegate?.swiftyDraw(shouldBeginDrawingIn: self, using: touch) ?? true else { return }
        delegate?.swiftyDraw(didBeginDrawingIn: self, using: touch)

        setTouchPoints(touch, view: self)
        let newLine = Line(path: CGMutablePath(),
                           brush: Brush(color: brush.color, width: brush.width, opacity: brush.opacity, blendMode: brush.blendMode))
        newLine.path.addPath(createNewPath())
        lines.append(newLine)
        drawingHistory = lines // adding a new line should also update history
    }
```

and touchesMoved

```
 override open func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard isEnabled, let touch = touches.first else { return }
        if #available(iOS 9.1, *) {
            guard allowedTouchTypes.flatMap({ $0.uiTouchTypes }).contains(touch.type) else { return }
        }
        delegate?.swiftyDraw(isDrawingIn: self, using: touch)

        updateTouchPoints(for: touch, in: self)
        let newPath = createNewPath()
        if let currentPath = lines.last {
            currentPath.path.addPath(newPath)
        }
    }
```

Touch ended

```
override open func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard isEnabled, let touch = touches.first else { return }
        delegate?.swiftyDraw(didFinishDrawingIn: self, using: touch)
    }
```

and Touch cancel

```
override open func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard isEnabled, let touch = touches.first else { return }
        delegate?.swiftyDraw(didCancelDrawingIn: self, using: touch)
    }
```

// and set TouchPint

```
private func setTouchPoints(_ touch: UITouch,view: UIView) {
        previousPoint = touch.previousLocation(in: view)
        previousPreviousPoint = touch.previousLocation(in: view)
        currentPoint = touch.location(in: view)
    }
```

// and updateTouchPoints

```
private func updateTouchPoints(for touch: UITouch,in view: UIView) {
        previousPreviousPoint = previousPoint
        previousPoint = touch.previousLocation(in: view)
        currentPoint = touch.location(in: view)
    }
```

and createNewPath

```
private func createNewPath() -> CGMutablePath {
        let midPoints = getMidPoints()
        let subPath = createSubPath(midPoints.0, mid2: midPoints.1)
        let newPath = addSubPathToPath(subPath)
        return newPath
    }
```

and  calculateMidPoint

```
private func calculateMidPoint(_ p1 : CGPoint, p2 : CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: (p1.x + p2.x) * 0.5, y: (p1.y + p2.y) * 0.5);
    }
```

and getMidPoints

```
private func getMidPoints() -> (CGPoint,  CGPoint) {
        let mid1 : CGPoint = calculateMidPoint(previousPoint, p2: previousPreviousPoint)
        let mid2 : CGPoint = calculateMidPoint(currentPoint, p2: previousPoint)
        return (mid1, mid2)
    }
```

and createSubPath

```
private func createSubPath(_ mid1: CGPoint, mid2: CGPoint) -> CGMutablePath {
        let subpath : CGMutablePath = CGMutablePath()
        subpath.move(to: CGPoint(x: mid1.x, y: mid1.y))
        subpath.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: mid2.x, y: mid2.y), control: CGPoint(x: previousPoint.x, y: previousPoint.y))
        return subpath
    }
```

and addSubPathToPath

```
 private func addSubPathToPath(_ subpath: CGMutablePath) -> CGMutablePath {
        let bounds : CGRect = subpath.boundingBox
        let drawBox : CGRect = bounds.insetBy(dx: -2.0 * brush.width, dy: -2.0 * brush.width)
        self.setNeedsDisplay(drawBox)
        return subpath
    }
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Question is how to draw like calligraphy pen as shown in image

Comment: Well that's extremely broad. There isn't some simple magic way.

Comment: The answer to this is almost certainly "lots of code, particularly if you want it to be customizable." As matt notes, there is no built-in solution to implementing pens. It's a complex topic, but certainly one you can learn. I would adopt iOS 13, which has made some of the technical details much simpler with PencilKit. But you'll still need to explore on your own how to get just the right look for your pen. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/221/?time=2014

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I Found simple  Solution :

```
 private func createSubPath(_ mid1: CGPoint, mid2: CGPoint) -> CGMutablePath {
        let subpath : CGMutablePath = CGMutablePath()
        subpath.move(to: CGPoint(x: mid1.x, y: mid1.y))
        subpath.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: mid2.x, y: mid2.y), control: CGPoint(x: previousPoint.x, y: previousPoint.y))
        for i   in 1 ..< 6 {
            subpath.addLines(between: [CGPoint(x: mid1.x + CGFloat(i), y: mid1.y + CGFloat(i)),CGPoint(x: mid2.x+CGFloat(i), y: mid2.y + CGFloat(i))])
         }
        return subpath
    }
```

Comment: you should also provide a simple explanation that could make this answer easy to understand for beginners.